# N inside Manipulate: evaluating and showing roots of quartic in real time

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate, polynomials, numerical-value

Consider the parameterized [quartic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4017295/614342%5D)

```
ClearAll[p];
p[m_, n_] := 
 Function[{x}, -7 - m - n + 
    m n + (-7 m - 8 n + 3 m n) x + (10 - 5 m - 8 n + m n) x^2 + (6 - 
       m - 2 n) x^3 + x^4 // Evaluate]
```

We are interested in the sum and product of roots for $m,n>4$. So this helps visualize the problem...

```
DynamicModule[
 {pt = {4, 4}, m, n},
 m = Dynamic[pt[[1]]];
 n = Dynamic[pt[[1]]];
 
 r = x /. NSolve[p[m, n][x] == 0, x];(*..............1*)
 s1 = r[[1]] + r[[2]];
 s2 = r[[3]] + r[[4]];
 p1 = r[[1]] r[[2]];
 p2 = r[[3]] r[[4]];
(*{s1}*)                             (*..............2*)
 
 {
  Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[pt]], PlotRange -> {{4, 10}, {4, 10}}, 
   Axes -> True],
  {N[s1, 5]}
  
  (*Column[{
  {m,n},
  {s1,s2,p1,p2}
  (*N/@{s1+s2,p1+p2+s1 s2,s1 p2+s2 p1,p1 p2}*)
  
  }]*)
  }
 ]
```

However as seen in this picture, the sum of roots isn't simplified to a single number but suspended to an expression with radicals.

[image: picture showing Locator with unevaluated root below]
Why does `N` not work here? (I did try the solver part-lines marked 1 to 2- outside `Manipulate` and it works as expected showing just a single evaluated number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use "Manipulate" and leave out the superfluous (in "Manipulate") "Dynamic". Here is the corrected code:

```
ClearAll[p];
p[m_, n_] := 
 Function[{x}, -7 - m - n + 
    m n + (-7 m - 8 n + 3 m n) x + (10 - 5 m - 8 n + m n) x^2 + (6 - 
       m - 2 n) x^3 + x^4 // Evaluate]

Manipulate[
 m = pt[[1]];
 n = pt[[1]];
 r = x /. NSolve[p[m, n][x] == 0, x];
 s1 = r[[1]] + r[[2]] // N;
 s2 = r[[3]] + r[[4]];
 p1 = r[[1]] r[[2]];
 p2 = r[[3]] r[[4]];
 {Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[pt]], PlotRange -> {{4, 10}, {4, 10}}, 
   Axes -> True], s1}
 , {{pt, {4, 4}}, Locator}
 ]
```

Comment: thnx..works..though can you please explain the meaning of passing `Locator` in `Manipulate`'s range spec

Comment: This is not a range spec but the controller type.